# Loop to replace element in an array

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I'm trying to "delete" an element from my struct and move the rest of my arrays below it up so it doesn't show a gap.

I can't, unfortunately, paste the code that I am using here. My teacher will be checking for plagiarism, so I really don't want to bother explaining that this is my own written code and risk my grade. I'll just try to explain the code instead.

I've got a code to call a function so I can find the position of the bank account that I wish to delete, which includes ID, first & last name, and balance.
This function also returns an integer, which I have named it c.

In my for loop `(j = c; j < totalAccs; j++)` I have included all of my arrays and int variables(from my struct), and by using strcpy I replace the element c ( the one that I found from calling another function). i.e. `strcpy(a[j].id,a[j+1].id)`.

I'm pretty sure that it's my loop that is completely wrong, but I am not sure what else to type in there.

My current problem is that whenever I execute this loop it replaces those arrays that I want to replace but it also types out a 0 at the end of my list.

Comment: `strcpy` can not be used for `struct`'s and you don't need a loop, [memmove](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27684119/c-method-for-moving-structs-between-dynamic-arrays) is your friend

Comment: After removing the element and filling the gap, `totalAccs` will be one less than before. You also shouldn't copy data fom one beyond the original `totalAccs` into the array.

Comment: You don't even need functions: a struct can be equated to another of the same type.

Comment: My teacher never mentioned memmove, so there's got to be another way.

Comment: There is, see previous comment. `mystruct[1] = mystruct[2]`, say.

Comment: @Keilara  So you can use `memmove` because your teacher didn't mentioned it ?

Comment: I'd rather learn the very basics before going into something else so I know what I am doing rather than not knowing.

Comment: As @AlterMann mentioned, you shouldn't be using `strcpy`, mainly because `strcpy` stops copying once it sees a 0 byte. Since you seem to have ints in your struct, your code may very well break if a 0 is present (ie. balance=0). If you are bent on using some sort of memory copy, use `memcpy` instead, it behaves the same as `strcpy` but does not stop at the 0 byte

Comment: For loop copy, back to front, the end of the buffer to the newly created "gap" - which is exactly what memmove does.